# Accessing private values in cpp using pointers

Tags: c++, accessor

For some reason the getter methods doesn't work. They are public, so I have no idea what's wrong.

```
for (std::vector<Document>:: const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << it->getName() << endl;
    counter += it->getLength();
}
```

> error: passing 'const Document' as 'this' argument of 'void Document::getName()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>                    cout << it->getName() << endl;
>
> error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and 'void')
>                    cout << it->getName() << endl;
>
> error: passing 'const Document' as 'this' argument of 'void Document::getLength()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>                    counter += it->getLength();
>
> error: invalid operands of types 'int' and 'void' to binary 'operator+'
>                    counter += it->getLength();

Hmm, is there a way to can we do `(int) (it->getLength())` for the last problem

and can we do for the other one:

```
std::ostringstream value;   
value << (*it).getName();
cout << getName << endl;
```

Comment: They're not `const`, so you can't call them with a `const_iterator`. It has nothing to do with accessibility and everything to do with const-correctness. And you can't print the result of something returning `void`.

Comment: ah ok, but the other two problems still remains. +1 for the rapid remark.

Comment: One of those addresses two errors and if you want to be pedantic, I could also say you can't add the result of something returning `void` to something else. I fail to see the other problem.

Comment: why does it return void though? ah nevermind silly me lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare the getters to be `const`:

```
class Document
{
public:
    std::string getName() const;
    int getLenght() const;
};
```

and specify their **return** values.

The error messages are not very readable, but in **gcc**:

```
error: passing A as B argument of C discards qualifiers
```

is almost always caused by trying to modify something that is `const`.

The other messages are clear however:

> error: no match for 'operator<<' 
>   (**operand types** are '**std::ostream** {aka std::basic_ostream}' and '**void**') 
>   cout << it->getName() << endl;

that is you are trying to pass a **std::ostream** and **void** to an operator.

Comment: have any idea why both are void?

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't show the relevant code, the error messages show enough to take a pretty good guess at the problem.

Your class apparently looks something like this:

```
class Document { 
// ...
public:
    void getName() { /* ... */ }   
    void getLength() { /* ... */ }
    // ...
};
```

To fix the problem, you need to change `getName` and `getLength` to 1) return values, and 2) be `const` member functions, something on this general order:

```
class Document { 
// ...
public:
    std::string getName() const { /* ... */ }   
    size_t getLength() const { /* ... */ }
    // ...
};
```